# Understanding Python help() 's ... syntax, and the pop function for dictionaries

Tags: python, function, methods, documentation

The `...` next to various python "help" method/function descriptions don't seem to be defined anywhere.    What does `function(...)` mean, in the context of the python `help` output description?

Specifically, how should the documentation for python's `pop` function be interpreted?

## Details

Given that the `pop` requires an input, it is a little confusing that `help({})`  doesn't show this in the functions input description (`...`).
Interpreting the `...` as  "ditto" doesn't work - for example, "items" cannot take any inputs.

To be clear, this is the functions input definition from `help`.

```
pop(...)
```

The full output of the `help({})` function, for `get`...`pop` is below.  What do the `...`'s mean, and, why is there no input defined, for the `pop` function?

```
     |  get(self, key, default=None, /)
     |      Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
     |  
     |  items(...)
     |      D.items() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's items
     |  
     |  keys(...)
     |      D.keys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys
     |  
     |  pop(...)
     |      D.pop(k[,d]) -> v, remove specified key and return the corresponding value.
     |      If key is not found, d is returned if given, otherwise KeyError is raised
```

Answer (score 0):

```
languages = ['Python', 'Java', 'C++', 'Ruby', 'C']
# here is a list
languages.pop(2)
# this will call the pop function for
# languages list and the it removes the element
# at the specified position.
# so after you take a look at languages
languages

Output: ['Python', 'Java', 'Ruby', 'C']
```

So as for your question. "pop" is a function so its usage is like any other function

thelist.pop(the-element-you-want-to-be-removed)